# Android - How to store html string in SQLite Database

Tags: android, html, sqlite

I have an html string I would like to store in my SQLite db "as is". The special characters in the html string prevent my `INSERT` statement from storing it:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('" + htmlString + "')
```

On iOS I used parameterized queries to accomplish this and it worked fine. How can I accomplish this on Android? I've Google parameterized queries for Android but the results were varied and unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Android you have parameterized queries too ... are few way to achive this:

```
ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
vals.putString("ColumnName", htmlString);
db.insert("myTable", null, vals);
```

or

```
final SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)");
insert.bindString(1, htmlString);
//edit: hehe forgot about most important thing 
insert.executeInsert();
```

or

```
db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)", new String[] {htmlString});
```

**EDIT:** (inserting multiple rows)

if you wana insert more than 1 row then do it in transaction (it should be quicker)
and prefer 2nd solution:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
  final SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (?)");
  for(...){
    insert.clearBindings();
    insert.bindString(1, htmlString[N]);
    //edit: hehe forgot about most important thing 
    insert.executeInsert();
  }
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is db.rawQuery the same as db.execSQL just with parameters?? Also, out of the 3 examples you provided, do you favor any one of them over the others?? And if so, why?

Comment: execSQL should not be use to SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ... if you need only 1 row then select one of those 3 (really doesn't matter) if you inserting multiple row  then see my edit